# How to retrieve values from pop up in a parent window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table tag in my Pop up window, in which the row can be dynamically inserted. I need to know how to retrieve the values correspond to the table in Parent window. Can you guys guide me to achieve this. I can retrieve the input box values, but not the rows in table.

Thanks

My pop up:

```
<form name="BREAKUP" method="POST" action="JavaScript:submitForm()">
    <br>
    <center>
    <TABLE id="PDetailsTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>SNO</td>
            <td>Team Name</td>
            <td>Estimated Hours</td>
            <td>Actual Hours</td>
            <td>Month</td>
        </tr>     

        <tr>
            <td > 1 </td>
            <TD ><INPUT id="TEAM_NME" ></TD>
            <TD ><INPUT id="EST_HRS"></TD>
            <TD ><INPUT id="ACT_HRS"></TD>
            <TD >
                <select id="MNTH" onchange="" size="1">
                    <option value="Jan">January</option>
                    <option value="Feb">February</option>
                    <option value="Mar">March</option>
                    <option value="Apr">April</option>
                    <option value="May">May</option>
                    <option value="Jun">June</option>
                    <option value="Jul">July</option>
                    <option value="Aug">August</option>
                    <option value="Sep">September</option>
                    <option value="Oct">October</option>
                    <option value="Nov">November</option>
                    <option value="Dec">December</option>
                </select>
            </TD>
        </tr>    
    </TABLE>

    <button value="Add Details" class="submitBtn" onclick="JavaScript:addRow('PDetailsTable');">
    <span>&nbsp;Add Details &nbsp;</span></button>

    <TABLE>
        <TR align="center" valign="top">
            <TD colspan="2"><img src="<%=imagesPath %>spacer.gif" height="10"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR valign="bottom">
            <TD colspan="2" align="center">
                <button TYPE="submit" class="submitBtn" onclick="JavaScript:submitForm();">
                <span>&nbsp;Submit &nbsp;</span></button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button value="Reset" class="submitBtn" onclick="JavaScript:resetForm();">
                <span>&nbsp;Reset&nbsp;</span></button>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

There are three javascript functions.
I am using windows.opener in submiForm Function. I don't know how to send a list of values and retrieve in the parent windows

Comment: Can you share some code or an example? better use jsFiddle...